# why this little constraint changes my whole program?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cplex, linearization, big-m

I'm trying to linearize a CP in ILOG CPLEX.

I have the following constraint that I want to linearize (I already simplified it with the big M) :

```
 forall(o1 in Operations){
      sum (o2 in Operations : o1!= o2)(zeta[o1][o2])<=1+M*(1- sum (o2 in Operations : o1!= o2)(Path_zeta[o1][o2])>=1);
    }
```

So I created a new boolean decision variable `x1` for each operations, `x1[o]` is equals to 1 iif there is at least one 1 for that operation o in the boolean matrix `Path_zeta` :

```
dvar int x1[Operations] in 0..1;
```

and in the constraint :

```
//we make sure that if there are no 1 for that operation, x1[o1] is equals to 0
forall(o1 in Operations){
    x1[o1] <= sum(o2 in Operations: o1 != o2)(Path_zeta[o1][o2]);}

// we make sure that if there is at least one 1 for that operation, x1[o1] is equals to 1
forall(o1 in Operations,o2 in Operations){
    x1[o1] >= (Path_zeta[o1][o2]);
  }
//and we can now rewrite the constraint with x1 
forall(o1 in Operations){
   sum (o2 in Operations : o1!= o2)(zeta[o1][o2])<=1+M*(1- x1[o1]);;
    }
```

when I launch my program with these new contraint, **i get a different optimal value** that changed the values of `Path_zeta` (it's not a valid affectation anymore).

In fact, with some debugging, I noticed that if I leave the non linear constraint as it is and I only add this one constraint to my program :

```
//we make sure that if there are no 1 for that operation, x1[o1] is equals to 0
forall(o1 in Operations){
    x1[o1] <= sum(o2 in Operations: o1 != o2)(Path_zeta[o1][o2]);}
```

I also have the same different result.

I don't understand how adding this only constraint change the result of my program : this is only supposed to change `x1`, not `Path_zeta`

Comment: When you say you get a "different optimal result", do you mean that the optimal objective value of the second model is different (better? worse?) than that of the first model, or that the first and second models yield the same objective value but different solutions?

Comment: my model with that constraint has an optimal objective value that is better than the model without but with incoherent values on ````Path_zeta````

Comment: Did you solve both problems to zero gap? If not, are the best bounds and best objective values imcompatible between the problems, i.e., optimal objective value of more constrained problem better than best bound of less constrained problem? Possibly badly scaled input data resulting in numerical difficulties and unreliability of solution. Perhaps you have a huge Big M value which causes havoc?

Comment: Try putting the path_zeta on the LHS of your constraint.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone you're right, it was the **BIG M fault,** it was too big ! 
Thanks, I would never have figured this out by myself !